# Windows 10 clean install stuck on white spinning dots

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, format, clean-install

I chose to do a complete reset of my Windows 10 PC where it completely wipes your hard drives. It went through the 0-100% just fine, but is now sitting at a black screen with white spinning dots. I've left this up for ~6 hours now and still nothing has changed. Im curious to know, does this usually take this long? Or is it actually stuck on something and I should reboot?

Comment: You choose Reset keep nothing or Refresh or Reset and choose to keep your personal files? Your title uses the words "clean install" your questions uses the word "Reset" while those actions are very similar what Windows does after it's finished installing Windows is very different; but no it's not normal

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion, i chose the option to completely remove all files. Reset keep nothing

Comment: Alright;  So what was the reason for using the Reset feature, was it for performance reasons?

Comment: Essentially, just finished schooling and had a ton of unused programs and files on the pc.

Comment: Decided to reboot pc, it seems to be installing windows now. I'll keep updating