# Windows 10 install immediately stuck on blue window logo

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, installation

I downloaded the [Windows 10 Enterprise trial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise) ISO, created a VirtualBox VM of the "*Windows 10 64bit*" type, gave it 2 CPU cores and 10GB of RAM, entered the ISO in its virtual DVD drive, and started it.

**PROBLEM**: The VM immediately shows the screen below, and stays like:

[image: Windows 10 blue logo]

It has been 3 hours already. I am using VirtualBox 5.0.18_Ubuntu on Ubuntu 2016.04 LTS, on 64bit hardware. VirtualBox uses 100% of the CPU, continuously.

Unlike [that other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1143806/windows-10-clean-install-stuck-on-white-spinning-dots), no 0%-100% progress, I did not get a chance to do anything, and no spinning dots.

I rebooted and the same problem happens.

I don't think my ISO is corrupt, as its SHA1 matches [that one](https://github.com/boxcutter/windows/blob/master/eval-win10x64-enterprise-ssh.json).

```
$ sha1sum 15063.0.170317-1834.RS2_RELEASE_CLIENTENTERPRISEEVAL_OEMRET_X64FRE_EN-US.ISO
6c60f91bf0ad7b20f469ab8f80863035c517f34f  15063.0.170317-1834.RS2_RELEASE_CLIENTENTERPRISEEVAL_OEMRET_X64FRE_EN-US.ISO
```

The .vbox file, if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings" version="1.15-linux">
  <Machine uuid="{5935f7d5-d1a9-4d64-9226-476a2332e1b2}" name="win10 CmisSync" OSType="Windows10_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2017-08-15T06:17:42Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{1770529d-a499-4f27-ad13-527e42021d37}" location="win10 CmisSync.vdi" format="VDI" type="Normal"/>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages>
        <Image uuid="{50c4d282-f892-4c2e-a117-1e33350396a1}" location="/home/nico/Downloads/15063.0.170317-1834.RS2_RELEASE_CLIENTENTERPRISEEVAL_OEMRET_X64FRE_EN-US.ISO"/>
      </DVDImages>
      <FloppyImages/>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="1702,414,1024,827"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeDevicesMenuActions" value="HardDrives"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RestrictedRuntimeMachineMenuActions" value="SaveState,PowerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/StatusBar/IndicatorOrder" value="HardDisks,OpticalDisks,FloppyDisks,Network,USB,SharedFolders,Display,VideoCapture,Features,Mouse,Keyboard"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware version="2">
      <CPU count="2" hotplug="false">
        <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExUX enabled="true"/>
        <PAE enabled="false"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="10039" PageFusion="false"/>
      <HID Pointing="USBTablet" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
      <HPET enabled="false"/>
      <Chipset type="PIIX3"/>
      <Paravirt provider="Default"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="Floppy"/>
        <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="3" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="128" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="false" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
      <VideoCapture enabled="false" screens="18446744073709551615" horzRes="1024" vertRes="768" rate="512" fps="25" maxTime="0" maxSize="0"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false" authType="Null"/>
      <BIOS>
        <ACPI enabled="true"/>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
        <Logo fadeIn="true" fadeOut="true" displayTime="0"/>
        <BootMenu mode="MessageAndMenu"/>
        <TimeOffset value="0"/>
        <PXEDebug enabled="false"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USB>
        <Controllers>
          <Controller name="OHCI" type="OHCI"/>
          <Controller name="EHCI" type="EHCI"/>
        </Controllers>
        <DeviceFilters/>
      </USB>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="08002757696B" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes/>
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="1" enabled="false" MACAddress="08002719D686" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="2" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800277BFA4D" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027463A06" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="4" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800276E56B5" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="5" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800277C0EC5" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="6" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800277C3F72" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="7" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800272E78E7" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
      <UART/>
      <LPT/>
      <AudioAdapter controller="HDA" driver="Pulse" enabled="true"/>
      <RTC localOrUTC="local"/>
      <SharedFolders/>
      <Clipboard mode="Disabled"/>
      <DragAndDrop mode="Disabled"/>
      <IO>
        <IoCache enabled="true" size="5"/>
        <BandwidthGroups/>
      </IO>
      <HostPci>
        <Devices/>
      </HostPci>
      <EmulatedUSB>
        <CardReader enabled="false"/>
      </EmulatedUSB>
      <Guest memoryBalloonSize="0"/>
      <GuestProperties>
        <GuestProperty name="/VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID" value="en_US" timestamp="1502777862354871000" flags=""/>
      </GuestProperties>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" hotpluggable="false" port="0" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{1770529d-a499-4f27-ad13-527e42021d37}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" hotpluggable="false" port="1" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{50c4d282-f892-4c2e-a117-1e33350396a1}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

Comment: "The VM immediately shows the screen below, and stays like this forever", I doubt you actually waited 'forever' ;) . How much time did you actually wait ? And probably relevant info as well: how much RAM was assigned to the VM ?

Comment: @Pacopaco: Not yet forever, you are right :-) I have been waiting for at least one hour now. I gave the VM 2 GB of RAM.

Comment: I restarted with 4GB of RAM, same problem so far.

Comment: What's the CPU on this machine? How many cores did you assign to the VM? Is the VM storage (vdi, and also the iso image) on a SSD or HDD? Check your current disk usage (`iotop`). Do you have hardware virtualisation (VT-x if Intel CPU) enabled?

Comment: @Bob: 100% of 1 CPU (out of 4), I believe VirtualBox means cores as my machine has four i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz cores. Th edisk is HDD and iotop shows no significant activity, in particular VirtualBox is stable at 0%. VT-x is enabled.

Comment: I would suggest giving it more (2-4 cores), at least for the install.

Comment: @Bob: Updated the question, now tested with 2 cores and 10 GB of RAM.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul With 2 cores, is CPU usage still at 100% for 3 hours?

Comment: @Ashton: Yes. Well, actually 102%, I guess one core at 100% + one core idling: https://i.imgur.com/wXsfU4w.png

Comment: Disconnect the network connection.

Comment: @GAD3R: I disconnected the host's Wi-Fi (so that the host and the guest have no network access), and restarted the VM. Same problem, blue logo and CPU at 100%, still the same after 3 minutes.

Comment: Hm. I just downloaded the exact same ISO (sha1sum match and all), and tried it on qemu-kvm, and it progressed past the pre-spinning-dots step in about 2 mins before spending another 3 mins on the spinning-dots step, before the first step of the installer. I'll see if I can get a VBox environment up. Any chance you can share your VM's configuration? Just the `.vbox` file should be enough.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks for investigating! I added the .vbox file to the question.

Comment: Hm. I can't reproduce your issue on VirtualBox 5.1.26 from the [non-free package](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) on Debian Stretch. Using your vbox config pointing at a new vdi and with RDP enabled (for RemoteBox). Are you able to run other OSes (Windows? Linux?) on your VirtualBox setup? (Unfortunately, I currently don't have a native Ubuntu system, and it's a bit hard to test a VM that requires VT-x when the 'host' is itself virtualised...)